# Unable to resize ec2 ebs root volume

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, partition

I have followed many of the tutorials that pretty much all say the same thing which is basically:

1. Stop the instance
2. Detach the volume
3. Create a snapshot of the volume
4. Create a bigger volume from the snapshot
5. Attach the new volume to the instance
6. Start the instance back up
7. Run `resize2fs /dev/xxx`

However, step 7 is where the problems start happening. In any case running `resize2fs` always tells me that it is already xxxxx blocks big and does nothing, even with `-f` passed. So I start to continue with tutorials which all basically say the same thing and that is:

1. Delete all partitons
2. Recreate them back to what they were except with the bigger sizes
3. Reboot the instance and run `resize2fs`

(I have tried these steps both from the live instance and by attaching the volume to another instance and running the commands there) The main problem is that the instance won't start back up again and the system error log provided in the AWS console doesn't provide any errors. (it does however stop at the grub bootloader which to me indicates that it doesn't like the partitions(yes, the boot flag was toggled on the partition with no affect)) The other thing that happens regardless of what changes I make to the partitions is that the instance that the volume is attached to says that the partition has an invalid magic number and the super-block is corrupt. However, if I make no changes and reattach the volume, the instance runs without a problem.

Can anybody shed some light on what I could be doing wrong?

---

**Edit**

On my new volume of 20GB with the 6GB image,`df -h` says:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvde1            5.8G  877M  4.7G  16% /
tmpfs                 836M     0  836M   0% /dev/shm
```

And `fdisk -l /dev/xvde` says:

```
Disk /dev/xvde: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2610 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x7d833f39

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvde1               1         766     6144000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/xvde2             766         784      146432   82  Linux swap / Solaris
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
```

Also, `sudo resize2fs /dev/xvde1` says:

```
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
The filesystem is already 1536000 blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Comment: Is the root partition the only one you have on that volume?

Comment: This particular image has `xvde1` as the root partition and `xvde2` as the swap

Comment: Try removing the swap partition, then resize2fs

Comment: I tried that, it still tells me that it is already as big as it can get.

Comment: So what's the output of fdisk -l /dev/xvde

Comment: I have edited my question with more information

Comment: Okay, so what does e2fsck give you for the partition?

Comment: It says there is a bad superblock. Even if I force it with `-b` with a block from `mke2fs -n`. However, it says that before I even make partition changes.

Comment: Is the partition a physical volume using lvm? And is it based off a public ami i can play with? I'm incredibly invested in this now.

Comment: You can create an identical instance using the following steps: `Launch Instance->Classic Wizard->Community AMIs->search "centos"->ami-00934969:"250188540659/CentOS 6.2 (Bare)"->Small/ec2/us-east-1a->[no advanced options]->[defaults on storage]`

Comment: @Decado Have you had a chance to try it?

Comment: A different approach might be to create a blank EBS volume (not from a snapshot), attach it to your instance, partition it, format the partition, and copy over the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take the safer route. And it looks like you are already doing things about as complicated. Attach the old volume to an instance launched with Amazon Linux or Ubuntu or whatever you are comfortable using. Mount it read/only. Then, create a new volume of the larger size you need. Attach it to the same instance at another device letter. Format it using the same label (or same UUID if your fstab mounts by UUID ... no real need for that in AWS but that is no assurance it isn't being done). Mount it read-write. Copy the file tree from the old volume to the new volume. You can use cp or rsync for that.

You may need to take other steps to make it bootable if you are not using PVGRUB "bootloader kernels" to load your real kernel from the volume.

Be sure to make a snapshot of the old volume before this, and a snapshot of the new volume after this.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the problem here is that you're tring to increase the size of the filesystem to fill up the partition, yet the partition hasn't actually increased in size.

The trick here will be to mount a snapshot of the volume onto a different instance as, say /dev/xdf. Then use parted or fdisk to remove the swap partition at /dev/xdf2.

```
parted /dev/xdf
rm 2
```

Then you can resize the other partition to fill the disk

```
parted /dev/xdf
resize 1
```

Then use the default for starting partition and an appropriate number for ending position. Then recreate the swap partition. 
Then if you run resize2fs /dev/sdf it should increase the size of the partition. Then unmount that disk and use it as the root volume of a new instance.

Comment: As I have stated in my original question, I have already done that a hundred different ways. Every time it corrupts the drive and is unable to start again. However, I tried it again just to see and got the same result. `resize2fs /dev/xvdj
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/xvdj
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.`, If it helps I am using a ext4 FS

Comment: Okay, could you do an fdisk -l after you resize the partition. That sounds like the start sector of the root partition changed. So with parted, specify the start sector with "1s".

Comment: I cannot use parted because I am using an ext4 FS.

Comment: Okay, so how does the fdisk output look after you resized the partitions using whatever tool it was you used to resize the partitions?

Comment: Identical start points, further end points, bigger sizes

Comment: You say identical start points, can you clarify that you mean same start point for the first partition, and a bigger number for the 2nd? Am sure you do, but just to confirm.

Comment: That is correct

Comment: I'd assume the disk was getting corrupted as you are still running with the swap partition enabled.  Disable it first `swapoff -a` then delete swap and resize the primary partition to fill the entire disk.  Everything else looks fine, it's just that swap is probably writing to the disk as you're working.

Answer (score 0):

Well, really the problem is you're using a poor AMI that sets up a swap partition.  Amazon virtual machines do not need swap partitions and the tutorials you have been following assume your EBS volume is not partitioned. I'd recommend starting with an [Ubuntu AMI from Alestic.com](http://alestic.com) or using an [Amazon Linux AMI](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/).

If you must continue to use the AMI you are using then what you need to do is delete the swap partition and resize the ext4 partition with `fdisk` and then you can resize the file system.  Doing that is fairly long and complicated and scary and I've never done it so I won't explain how to do it.  You can find instructions via Google if you dare.